# How many modules are required to clear administrator exam?

Tags: administration

I want to change from **digital marketing to salesforce**. There are 2 roles here: developer and administrator. I want to go for the administrator role.
Having wasted 2 years in programming i got a break in digital marketing but I am very worried about the programming part in administrator role.Have finished my first assignment on https://login.salesforce.com/.
In the first part I followed the module and edited a field in object manager.Found an online trainer but he asking for a 400 dollar (18000 rs) fee I dont want to take any chances so will be training under him .[image]

Comment: All of the details about the exams are on the Salesforce [Certification](http://certification.salesforce.com/administrator) site. Administrator is a single exam, no modules.

Comment: Have you done any research so far? Are you trying to pass a specific certification? Please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about what you are asking.

Comment: yes certification  - (ADM 201), for administrator which gets me a job in salesforce

Comment: 400 dollars! Mate go on trail head

Comment: okies and companies are asking for atleast one live project too https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/force_com_admin_beginner/modules/starting_force_com/units/starting_discovering second class on trailhead but how will i get a live project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None. The exam [documentation](http://certification.salesforce.com/administrator) states:

> No prerequisites, however; Administration Essentials for New Admins (ADM 201), and  Administration Essentials for New Admins and Certification (ADM 201C), are recommended

There is a [practice exam](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Administrator-Practice-Test/?q=admin%20practice%20test&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1) you can take for 20 USD if you're unsure that you're ready, which can help identify your strengths and weaknesses in order to prepare for the real test.